# How to input text in the World up object / World up object 2 using MEL scripting

Tags: scripting, mel

I want to input text in the World up object and World up object2.
('Enable twist control' for the ik handle in the attribute editor)

I used :
`setAttr "Spine_ikHandle.stringWorldUpObject" -type "string" "Hip_joint"`

which does not work.

What am i doing wrong?
Is it because it's just a text field and not an attribute?
MEL command reference is currently slight confusing to a me as a beginner.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Those Ik handle attributes need a connection from the control objects. Connect the worldMatrix attribute like so.

```
connectAttr -f Hip_Twist_Locator.worldMatrix[0] Spine_ikHandle.dWorldUpMatrix;
connectAttr -f Foot_Twist_Locator.worldMatrix[0] Spine_ikHandle.dWorldUpMatrixEnd;
```

The text fields in the attribute editor will reflect the connected object names. 
If you connect different objects using `connectAttr`, the fields will update.
If you type in the field the name of an existing transform, that object's worldMatrix will be connected when enter is pressed. This is due to the way the attribute editor template has been written for that specific node. 
The `setAttr` command won't cause the connection to happen.